# Copiar linhas de uma tabela que correspondam a um critério e colar noutra folha de Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Olá! Sou algo novo no VBA e tenho obtido o que pretendo através do gravador de macros. No entanto, penso que neste caso não vá conseguir o que pretendo através desse recurso. Tentarei ser claro no meu objetivo.

A minha folha de Excel chama-se `"A3"` e nessa folha tenho uma tabela localizada entre  `P10:AA25`. Os dados estão nas linhas entre `P13:AA25` e na coluna Z tenho as palavras `OPEN/CLOSED`. Pretendia criar uma macro copiasse e limpasse as linhas `DA TABELA` que possuem o critério `"CLOSED"` e as colasse numa tabela localizada entre `A1:L16` na folha `"AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS"`.

Agradeço desde já toda a ajuda!

Comment: Bom Dia.
O Stack Overflow tem foco em perguntas e resposas para casos concretos onde se verificou dificuldade no desenvolvimento de alguma solução.
Você desenvolveu algum código? Tentou algo que não deu certo?
Pelo que vi parece o que você quer é uma solução pronta, mas aqui a colaboração é para tirar dúvidas.
Estude um pouco de VBA básico e rascunhe sua própria solução.
Quando tentar implementá-la antes, se houver algum erro volte aqui que ajudamos.

Answer (score 2):

Como você não deu um exemplo do código montei esse daqui com o que você passou. Faça os testes ou [confira a lógica aqui](https://www.aprenderexcel.com.br/2016/vba/como-copiar-ou-separar-valores-com-criterios-no-excel) e tente aplicar ao seu caso.

Insira o seguinte código na planilha a ter os valores analisados e separados:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Range("A1:L16").ClearContents

 For I = 13 To 25
   If Worksheets("A3").Cells(I, 26) = "OPEN" Then Exit For
   If Worksheets("A3").Cells(I, 26) = "CLOSED" Then
    Linha = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Range("A1:L16"))
    Linha = Linha + 2
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 1) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 16)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 2) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 17)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 3) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 18)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 4) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 19)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 5) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 20)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 6) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 21)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 7) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 22)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 8) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 23)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 9) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 25)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 10) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 25)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 11) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 26)
    Worksheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS").Cells(Linha, 12) = Worksheets("base").Cells(I, 27)
   End If
  Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Fiz alguma alterações. Portanto, se você testou antes e não obteve sucesso, teste novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma é filtrar na `coluna Z` da tabela por `CLOSED` e copiar toda a área visível e depois limpá-la. Assim é mais otimizado do que fazer a iteração uma por uma.

```
Dim a3 As Worksheet, FECHADA As Worksheet
    Set a3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A3")
    Set FECHADA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AÇÕES PDCA FECHADAS")

    With a3
        'Limpa os Autofiltros da Planilha para evitar erros
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
        'Última Linha da coluna Z
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRow2 = FECHADA.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'AutoFiltro
        .Range(.Cells(10, 16), .Cells(LastRow, 27)).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="CLOSED"
        'Cria range com as células visíveis após Filtrar
        On Error Resume Next
        Set VisibleRange = .Range(.Cells(10, 16), .Cells(LastRow, 27)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not VisibleRange Is Nothing Then
            'Copia as células visíveis após aplicação do AutoFiltro
            'E cola na Planilha de destino
            VisibleRange.Copy Destination:=FECHADA.Cells(LastRow2+1,1)
        End If

        'Limpa a Range
        VisibleRange.Clear

        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If

    End With
```